# Can you protect graphical designs through written form?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

Let's say you design a spider-man costume, but instead of drawing it you write it. To what extent can you protect a graphical design through written form? Using common sense, I would say no since the costume in written form could be drawn in too many ways, but is there a situation where some of the elements may be able to be protected as an intellectual property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The written description itself is protected by copyright. A drawing made by a third party that was based on the text would *not* be a derivative work of the text.